# Heroku view is having trouble

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

One specific page is not working on Heroku even though it is working fine in local.

This is my controller for the action

```
def artist_with_limit
    require 'uri' 
    require 'open-uri' 
    require 'nokogiri' 
end
```

This is view page

```
        <% @changed = URI::encode(songartist) %>
        <% linkurl = "https://www.ufret.jp/artist.php?data="+@changed %>
        <% doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(linkurl)) %>
        <% @artistnum = doc.xpath(" //a [@class= 'list-group-item list-group-item-action normal-chord']/strong").children.count %>
```

It works perfectly fine but it is not working for Heroku. 
This is what the Heroku log says

```
at=info method=GET path="/mylist_artist" host=nfret25.herokuapp.com request_id=b2f6e0c6-fd15-4bb3-97c0-0f9ab45670fb fwd="73.25.151.219" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=33ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
```

Comment: No error message? You may have installed the gems (nokogiri, ..) only for the development environment. Did you check it from Gemfile? It needs to be installed for the production environment (or whatever).

Comment: Don't put that sort of logic into a view. It should be in a controller. Also, be careful opening pages from remote sites when your code is trying to process a request from a customer or user, because, if that remote site is slow or doesn't respond, your code will freeze waiting. Instead, if you know the site's URL ahead of time, write a little Ruby code that can run outside of Rails and process the page, storing the information you want in a database, which is then pulled by the Rails code when needed. Speed and robustness are important.

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri question. Please tag accurately. Just because your code uses Nokogiri isn't sufficient, only tag if it's actively a part of the problem. It'd also probably help if you read "[ask]" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We can't run your code, so duplicating the problem is difficult, and as a result we have to guess at the problem.